# How To Read Data Into A List Structure in C#?

Tags: c#, list, structure

I am writing a program that uses a StudentStruct (structure) that consists of: studentID, studentName, and grades (which is a separate List). The program is supposed to read in a sequential text file and contains methods that allow the user to: Add Student, Add Grades (to a particular student), Change Student Name, and Delete Student. At the end of the program it is supposed to overwrite the previous file with the new changes made from the current program session.

My question is how do I read in data from the text file into the separate structure variables within the lists?

My text file looks like this:

```
00000,Mimzi Dagger,100,50,75,70,45,10,98,83
00001,Alexander Druaga,89,45,80,90,15,73,99,100,61
00002,Nicholas Zarcoffsky,100,50,80,50,75,100,100
00003,Kantmiss Evershot,50,100
```

Once the structure variables within the list are filled, how do I overwrite the file with the contents of the List structure in the same format as the above file?

Since I have multiple and varying amounts of grades, how would I achieve looping through and adding each grade to the grades list?

As you can maybe already tell, I am very new to c# and this is my first project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    class Program
    {
        static string pathSource = @"C:\schoolfiles\StudentGrades.txt";

        struct StudentStruct
        {
            public string studentID;
            public string studentName;
            public List<string> grades;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StudentStruct student = new StudentStruct();
            List<StudentStruct> myList = new List<StudentStruct>();
            student.grades = new List<string>();
        }
```

UPDATE: Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
{
    output = fileLines[i];
    string[] outputArray = output.Split(',');

    student.grades = new List<string>();
    student.studentID = outputArray[0];
    student.studentName = outputArray[1];

    for (int j = 2; j < outputArray.Length; j++)
    {
        student.grades.Add(outputArray[j]);
    }

    myList.Add(student);
```

UPDATE: The code above worked out wonderfully. Here is the top part of my code involving this question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare variables
        string output;

        //Read the File into an array
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(PathSource);

        StudentStruct student = new StudentStruct();
        List<StudentStruct> myList = new List<StudentStruct>();



        for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
        {
            output = fileLines[i];
            string[] outputArray = output.Split(',');

            student.grades = new List<string>();
            student.studentID = outputArray[0];
            student.studentName = outputArray[1];

            for (int j = 2; j < outputArray.Length; j++)
            {
                student.grades.Add(outputArray[j]);
            }

            myList.Add(student);
        }

        MainMenu(myList);
    }
```

And then to add the list back to the file I did this:

```
static void ExitModule(List<StudentStruct> myList)
    {
        //Declare variables
        string inputChoice = null;
        string output = null;

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(PathSource);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Are You Sure You Want To Exit The Program? Y/N");
        inputChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (inputChoice == "Y" || inputChoice == "y")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
            {
                output = (myList[i].studentID + "," + myList[i].studentName);

                for (int j = 0; j < myList[i].grades.Count; j++)
                {
                    output += ("," + myList[i].grades[j]);
                }

                file.WriteLine(output);
            }

            file.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: You can easily parse the line (according the comma) and then add the node to the list (using new student structure each time)

Comment: I can't test it though, as I am having trouble figuring out the syntax on how to pass a list with a nested list.

Comment: Do not post code in comments. Edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is clearly homework, it may be a good time for you to learn about [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure). This will help you store the information you've read in from the text file efficiently, allowing you to write it out much more easily after modifying the records.

Here are a couple of other random pointers:

- The `System.IO.File.ReadLines(pathSource)` method would be a good place to start reading each line of a text file
- You should almost never be using a `struct` in C# (especially one that is mutable like in your example) unless you are well-versed in its semantics and purpose. Use a `class` instead

Comment: One of the stipulations is that I must use a structure and I can only have 1 class.

Comment: If the exact verbiage in the assignment is use a `struct` with only 1 `class`, then I suppose that's what you have to do to pass. Just make sure to note that it is deeply wrong to be using a `struct` in this way, and forget you've done it this way once the assignment is complete.

Comment: Yep, I used the .ReadLines to read the file into an array, which I then split and used a for loop to put the variables into the list elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this code. it's working for me

```
class Program
    {
        static string pathSource = @"C:\schoolfiles\StudentGrades.txt";

        struct StudentStruct
        {
            public string studentID;
            public string studentName;
            public List<string> grades;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StudentStruct student = new StudentStruct();
            List<StudentStruct> myList = new List<StudentStruct>();
            student.grades = new List<string>();

            // get all lines from text file
            string[] allLinesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(pathSource);

            // iterate through each line and process it
            foreach(string line in allLinesFromFile)
            {
                // split each line on ','
                string[] sections = line.Split(',');
                student.studentID = sections[0];
                student.studentName = sections[1];

                // use this loop to add numbers to list of grades
                for(int i =2; i < sections.Length; i++)
                {
                    student.grades.Add(sections[i]);
                }

                // add this student to list
                myList.Add(student);

                // create new object of student
                student = new StudentStruct();
                student.grades = new List<string>();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

(1) I am not sure why your teacher/professor would have you use a struct here. A class is much more appropriate. `I actually cringed when I first saw the code`

(2) having something as a const also implies that it is static `"pathSource"`

(3) Properties should be capitalized `"pathSource" -> "PathSource"`

(4) You should separate responsibilities... Try not to put everything in Main

(5) You shouldn't have to create an instance of grades outside of `StudentStruct`, this can lead to errors. i.e. `NullPointerException`... basically the struct should be self containing.

(6) Everything should compile. I haven't tested it. If you have any issues. let me know.

```
Program {
    private const string PathSource = @"C:\schoolfiles\StudentGrades.txt";

    private struct StudentStruct
    {
        public string StudentID;
        public string StudentName;

        private List<string> _gradeList;

        public List<string> GradeList
        {
            // if _gradeList is null create a new instance
            get { return _gradeList ?? (_gradeList = new List<string>()); }
            private set { _gradeList = value; }
        }
    }

    private static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var studentFile = File.ReadAllLines( PathSource );
        // If you haven't learned about delegates or extensions methods...
        // You can just change it to a foreach statement
        var myList = studentFile.Select( GetStudent ).ToList();

        // make sure we have everything
        foreach (var studentStruct in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "{0}  {1}", studentStruct.studentName, studentStruct.studentID );
            foreach (var grade in studentStruct.GradeList) { Console.Write( grade + " " ); }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static StudentStruct GetStudent( string line )
    {
        var student = new StudentStruct();
        var studentDelimited = line.Split( ',' );

        student.studentID = studentDelimited[ 0 ];
        student.studentName = studentDelimited[ 1 ];

        for ( int i = 2; i < studentDelimited.Length; i++ ) { student.GradeList.Add( studentDelimited[ i ] ); }

        return student;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since grades is a list within a list I thought I would need to initialize a new list each time I needed a new grades list for each student. I think my teacher is making us do it this way to later show us an easier, more efficient way to write code.

Comment: My Main() method had to be used to load the file into the list. I have separate methods for all other functions needed in the program. Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, in the above code, every time a new "Student" is created a new list would be "initialized".